# How to cofigure tomcat server in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using Eclipse classical 3.7.2 and i want to configure tomcat server in eclipse IDE for developing some servlet programs.If anyone know guide me.thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new server under the Servers tab in the Java EE view.

Then on the second page you point Eclipse to your Tomcat installation directory (usually the parent directory of where your Tomcat binaries are).